# Getting columns with padding the same width in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns, padding

I am working on the following website: http://jellekok.com/new/work.php

Because the first 3 items have no right padding, and the 4th one has, the last one is less high. I want them to be the same width, is there an easy way to do that? I am using Bootstrap 4.

Code:

```
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
        <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
        <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
        <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 work_item">
        <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use `px-2` on all of them for a smaller gutter between the columns...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 px-2 col-lg-3 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img class="mw-100" src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 px-2 col-lg-3 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img class="mw-100" src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 px-2 col-lg-3 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img class="mw-100" src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 px-2 col-lg-3 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img class="mw-100" src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/WaF5e840pT

Comment: this creates less margin on the outer side then between the items.. i want the margins to be everywhere 15px.

Answer (score 0):

You can add bootstrap 4 class img-fluid to your image elements and same time add pr-0 to the fourth element as well in order to make it same height.
Link for code here :-
https://jsfiddle.net/vnombqkh/
Below is code you can check and test:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>

      </div>


      <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/inforintelligence_intro_960.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/exchange_party_halloween_poster.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/new/img/index_brouwerij_frankendael.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/855_page_head_combo_alt.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>

      </div>


      <div class="row mt-3">
         <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/flyer_bno_img_lab_pioniers_960_v2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/sequence_zero_bespreekruimte_960.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/posters_folders_row.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/fotoboek1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/bobbie_wall_play_cover.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pr-0 work_item">
            <a href="exchange-party.php"><img src="http://jellekok.com/img/ynter_home_960.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only in your example, there's no margin on the right side? The paddings between the images have to be the same width as the right and left margin of the whole site/content.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to got it working while doing this:

Step 1: adding class "pr-0" to every of the 4 columns (this will put the fourth and most right item completely to the right of the screen).
Step 2: adding class "pr-3" to the outer "row" class, creating a margin on the right side of the div.